# How to get the stock price data of a Korean company up to the current date?

Tags: curated-data

I called stock price data for Korean companies (005930.KS) as follows.

```
FinancialData["005930.KS", All]
FinancialData["005930.KS", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2022, 2, 27}}]
```

However, this value is not data until the current date.

[image]

I want to continue to get updated data every day.
How to get the stock price data of a Korean company up to the current date?